# copying fields and field dependencies from one object to another

Tags: apex, force.com

I have a controlling field with a bunch of  field dependencies on Opportunities. I want to have the same controlling field with the same field dependencies to a subset of those fields.

Is there a quick way to do this? maybe via copying and pasting from the XML in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML would be the fastest way - yes. *I don't think there is a way to clone a field and dependencies in the point/click UI.*

Comment: any advice on working with the XML? Do i just copy it, and paste it anywhere into the other object's XML?

Comment: well depending on how big the object is, use a structured editor so you can easily see what your moving around. I've seen objects XML from Salesforce in excess of 20k lines long.

Comment: Attempt to save the object and look at the API results, and than try to match it from there.